# Always use fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Big Nerd Ranch's Android Programming, it advocates AUF (always use fragment). Specifically, it has this to say:

> "...adding fragments later can be a minefield. Changing an activity to
>   an activity hosting a UI fragment is not difficult, but there are
>   swarms of annoying gotchas. Keeping some interfaces managed by
>   activities and having others managed by fragments only makes things
>   worse because you have to keep track of this meaningless distinction.
>   It is far easier to write your code using fragments from the beginning
>   and not worry about the pain and annoyance of reworking it later, or
>   having to remember which style of controller you are using in each
>   part of your application."

The book doesn't expound on what the annoying gotchas are.  What are the gotchas?

Comment: "What are the gotchas?" -- something that swarms, apparently. Since they're based in Georgia, I'm thinking perhaps gnats. :-) I cannot think of any particular challenges in switching an activity to use fragments compared to putting in fragments at the outset.

Comment: Would you advice not always use fragment as they advocate?

Comment: @CommonsWare I can think of one - having fragments inside activities, and using `onActivityResult` callback. When later swapping activities for fragments, you end up with nested fragments, and fragments further the road don't get `onActivityResult` callback properly. If I'm wrong please let me know (I did have problems with it in the past), and while you can make it work, I'd certainly qualify this as *gotcha*

Comment: @wasyl: I avoid nested fragments at all costs.

Comment: @Boon: Given a choice between "always fragments" and "never fragments", I'd go "always fragments". Given a choice between "always fragments" and "gee, can't we actually be intelligent developers and think through whether this technique makes sense in this situation, since this is a bit of a strategic decision, rather than blindly following some 'always do X' advice", I'd go with the latter, even though it is wordy. :-)

Comment: @Boon there goes this, then. Using fragments from the beginning helps you avoid having to restructure your code to avoid nested fragments further down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest of all is Context. as Activity is driven by Context (not directly). when you need context in an activity you have it there all the time. same is not with the case with fragment, in fragments you can call getActivity method to get parent activity but when porting code from Activity to fragment you have to deal with supplying it everywhere.

Another problem could be life cycle of Activity.  where activity lifecycle is simple and functions like onResume, onPause are pleasure to use same can not be said for fragments. Adapting things which were designed for Activity life cycle into fragment life cycle can be nightmare.

Having said that, if things are not complex and you need to handle only one task it is safe to go with activity to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are at the very start of decision making, I want to leave this here:
https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html

On the bottom line, this blog says that the lifecycle of a fragment is too complicated and therefore it advocates against using fragments, in favor of an Model-View-Presenter-Pattern

A personal note: the wordy comment from CommonsWare hits the spot. I blindly used fragments because they were there and I never questioned them. But after reading the above article, I've changed my mind.

Comment: Above link is dead. https://developer.squareup.com/blog/advocating-against-android-fragments/